# how to create UIView with 3d object

Tags: iphone, uiview, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller

How can I create UIView with 3d object (for example:box)? And then add this UIView to my UIViewController where I output image from camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use OpenGL ES layer to achieve this.